# Export characters from PPT

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

I need to export every character of word (which has animation for every character) inside slide separatelly.

Can it be done by `Shape.export()` method? currentlly it's export whole word inside shape.

Comment: Check out [this link](http://mantascode.com/c-get-text-content-from-microsoft-powerpoint-file/). It provides you with an example in C# on how to extract all text for each slide.

Comment: Do you need to export each character within the word as a graphic file containing just the character, or do you want to export the slide once for each stage of the animation?